# error: package android.support.design.button does not exist

Tags: android

In my build.gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 6

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0@aar') { transitive = true; }

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.yuyh.json:jsonviewer:1.0.6'
```

In my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/viewJsonButton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> handler.onClickViewJson(item)}"
                    android:text="@string/view_json"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

But when I try to start my android app I get error:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin
> Task :app:dataBindingExportFeaturePackageIdsDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Gradle may disable incremental compilation as the following annotation processors are not incremental: databinding-compiler-3.3.2.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:3.3.2).
Consider setting the experimental feature flag android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true in the gradle.properties file to run annotation processing in a separate task and make compilation incremental.
D:\dev\myproject\android\TM\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\myproject\android\databinding\TraderListItemBinding.java:3: error: package android.support.design.button does not exist
import android.support.design.button.MaterialButton;
                                    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add dependency of your Material Button.

Comment: I changed to <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton. And now it's work fine.